# How to generate Content Encryption Key for JWE implementation

Tags: encryption, jwe, jceks

I am trying to learn and implement JWE in java for a problem statement. I am trying to understand how does the Content Encryption Key is generated using a certain algorithm(let's say RSA-PKCS1_1.5).

I have knowledge on how to generate a pair of the key using the key generator, then using the public key for encryption and private key for decryption. Also, I am aware of how to create a simple JWT token by giving claims and also how to sign them.
I am trying to follow the steps:

The message encryption process is as follows:

Generate a random Content Encryption Key (CEK). The CEK MUST have a length at least equal to that of the required encryption keys and MUST be generated randomly.

Encrypt the CEK for the recipient

Generate a random IV (if required for the algorithm).

Compress the Plaintext if a zip parameter was included.

Serialize the (compressed) Plaintext into a bitstring M.

Encrypt M using the CEK and IV to form the bitstring C.

Set the Encoded JWE Ciphertext equal to the base64url encoded representation of C.

Create a JWE Header containing the encryption parameters used.

Base64url encode the bytes of the UTF-8 representation of the JWE Header to create the Encoded JWE Header.

The three encoded parts, taken together, are the result of the encryption.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        //ASYMMETRIC ENCRYPTION
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair keys = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        byte[] publicKey = keys.getPublic().getEncoded();
        byte[] privateKey = keys.getPrivate().getEncoded();

        System.out.println("PUBLIC KEY  ::: " + Base64.encodeBase64String(publicKey));
        System.out.println("PRIVATE KEY ::: " + Base64.encodeBase64String(privateKey));

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        //PUBLIC KEY IS GETTING USED IN ENCRYPTING PLAIN TEXT
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keys.getPublic());
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal("Test String".getBytes());
        //PRIVATE KEY IS GETTING USED IN DECRYPTING CIPHER TEXT
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keys.getPrivate());
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);

        System.out.println("encrypted data  ::: " + BaseEncoding.base64().encode(encryptedBytes));
        System.out.println("decrypted text ::: " + new String(decryptedBytes));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Key Management Mode

The key management mode is used to determine the CEK. Each algorithm uses one of these modes.
Hereafter the list of available modes and algorithm associations:

- Key Encryption: `RSA1_5`, `RSA-OAEP`, `RSA-OAEP-256`, `RSA-OAEP-384`, `RSA-OAEP-512`
- Key Wrapping: `A128KW`, `A192KW`, `A256KW`, `PBES2-HS256+A128KW`, `PBES2-HS384+A192KW`, `PBES2-HS512+A256KW`, `A128GCMKW`, `A192GCMKW`, `A256GCMKW`
- Direct Key Agreement: `ECDH-ES`
- Key Agreement with Key Wrapping: `ECDH-ES+A128KW`,  `ECDH-ES+A192KW`,  `ECDH-ES+A256KW`
- Direct Encryption: `dir`

#### How to determine the CEK?

- With **Key Encryption**, **Key Wrapping** and **Key Agreement with Key Wrapping**, the CEK is a random byte string. Its size depends on the Content Encryption Algorithm.
- With **Direct Key Agreement**, the CEK is the agreed upon key computed using the sender and receiver keys.
- With **Direct Encryption**, the CEK is the shared symmetric key.